# How was this inequality solved?

Tags: probability, inequality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/386Jd.jpg)

I can’t not seem to know how this inequality was solved here.

Comment: Why you use the tag probability in this question?

Comment: This was in a probability text book, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We probably know in advance that $a,b > 1$. Since all sides of the inequality are positive, we can take the square root from all sides and we have:
$$ \frac{a-1}{a+b-1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt3} < \frac{a}{a+b}$$
Now for the right inequality, we have $ a+b < \sqrt3 \times a \implies (\sqrt3-1)a > b \implies a > \frac{b}{\sqrt3 -1}$
Multiply the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt3 +1$ and you get
$$ a > \frac{\sqrt3+1}{2} \times b$$
The other inequality is obtained with the same method.